# Azure B2C Facebook SignUp through the app

Tags: ios, facebook, azure, facebook-login, azure-ad-b2c

I've got a mobile app (native iOS/Android), which uses B2C for authentication through social networks, in particular through Facebook.

MSAL library opens a browser for the authentication where user can just pass their username and password.

Is it possible to provide a page, where user will have to choose an authentication method, pass username/password, or do it through the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

You could add Facebook as the identity provider. By this, when you open the sign in or up page, there will be a choice to select the facebook.

For the details about adding Facebook as the identity provider, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app).